# Adjusting OCXO frequency via VFC pin

Tags: rf

I have a used OCXO [Morion MV85](http://www.morion.com.ru/catalog_pdf/8_MV85.pdf). According to datasheet linked above, it has GND, VCC or U<sub>in</sub>, RF out and VFC pins. As far as I was able to find out by googling, the purpose of VFC pin is to adjust oscillation frequency via its voltage. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find an example circuit diagram showing the connection of VFC pin to anything. Here is my best guess so far: 
[image: OCXO circuit]

Reference pin **accepts**, not provides volatge, and should receive one between VCC an some value, determined by R1 resistance. Adjusting R1 should affect frequency at RF OUT pin.

My question is - am I right

- Providing voltage to VREF
- Making its value between VCC and something (maybe I should add one more resistor in series)?

Comment: Your question would be more clear if you used the same pin labels in your schematic as are used in the datasheet.

Comment: @ThePhoton Unfortunately I don't have a device for this one in Eagle :(

Comment: So make a new symbol, or use a different tool to draw the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drive the VFC pin with a potentiometer set up as a voltage divider between the reference voltage and ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1puQem.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. Using that circuit I was able to adjust the frequency to match rubidium oscillator.

Answer (score 2):

> Reference pin accepts, not provides volatge,

Based on the datasheet, this appears to be incorrect:

[image]

If the datasheet describes the pin as an output, it usually means it is an output from the chip, not an input to the chip. And  by "usually" I mean in every instance I've ever heard of.

The intent of this pin is probably to provide a reference for a DAC to be used to drive the `Uin` pin. Or, for manual control you could connect a potentiometer between `Uref` and ground, and connect the wiper to `Uin`.

Sometimes it's possible to override a reference output pin with an external voltage, but I don't see anything in this (rather terse) datasheet to indicate that is possible with this chip.

Comment: Frequently the 'reference' is just a zener diode -- so you can't override it in practice. Also, it can probably only support a load of < 1 mA -- so 100 ohm will be too low of a potentiometer resistance -- suggest 10k or 47 kohm.

Comment: I agree with Photon. The frequency can be pulled by applying 0 to 4.5 volts on Uin with a 20k potentiometer. This is clearly stated in the datasheet.

Comment: @jp314, I'd just use 20 kohms like the datasheet recommends.